# Register page is not found 404

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2, laravel-7

This is my routes.js page

```
import login from "./components/auth/login";
import register from "./components/auth/register";

export const routes =[

{path : '/',component:login,name:'/'},
{path : '/register',component:register,name:'register'}
]
```

This is my app.js page

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import {routes} from './routes';
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode:'history'
})
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

This is my welcome.blade.php page

```
<body id="page-top">
    <div id="app">
  <div id="wrapper">
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my register.vue page

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="display-4">
            Register Form
        </h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

While 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/register' page is loaded then it shows page not found 404.
I think i am not able to properly able to connect vue with laravel.
I am using vue2 and larave7. What is the correct method to connect vue with laravel